# C program hangs after creating file

Tags: c

I'm doing an exercise for University, which asks:

**Create a C program called 'split', which accepts a file, and a number. The program will divide the input file in two files, one called 'part1.txt' which will contain the first n bytes, and one called 'part2.txt' which will contain the other bytes.
If the input file contains less than n bytes, the file 'part2.txt' will not be created.**

This is my program. What happens when I execute it, is that it creates the part1.txt file (without anything written in it) and the program hangs.
I've been looking at this for a day, but can't spot the problem. Any help?

I've compiled using:

```
gcc -o split split.c
```

When i execute it, i write:

```
./split text.txt 10
```

Where 'text.txt' is a text file containing words i accurately typed by pressing random buttons on my keyboard.

```
int splitter;
int fd, fd1, fd2;
char buffer[5000];

int main(int argc, char** argv){

if(argc<2){
  printf("Insert 2 arguments.");
  exit(1);
}

splitter = atoi(argv[2]);

if (fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) < 0){
  perror("Error\n");
  exit(1);
} else {
  if (fd1=open("part1.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU) <0){
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
  }
  if(read(fd,buffer,splitter) == splitter){
    write(fd1,buffer,splitter);
    if (fd2=open("part2.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)<0){
      perror("Errore");
      exit(1);
    };
    while (read(fd,buffer,1) ==1){
      write(fd2,buffer,1);
    }
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
  } else {
    while (read(fd,buffer,1) ==1){
      write(fd1,buffer,1);
    }
    close(fd1);
  }
  close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you including how you're running it and the files you're providing as input?

Comment: I've added more info

Comment: if condition braces are missing it should be `if ((fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)` other one also for fd1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relational operators reside at the `6th` level of `C`'s precedence table, much higher than the assignment operators.

This statement:

```
if (fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) < 0)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (fd = (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) < 0))
```

The `<` operator returns either `1` or `0`, or in other words, `true` or `false`, which gets assigned to `fd`.

Change it to:

```
if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
```

You have the same issue in the subsequent `if` statement.

---

*From Expert C Programming:*

> Some authorities recommend that there are only two precedence levels
> to remember in C: multiplication and division come before addition and
> subtraction.
> Everything else should be in parentheses. We think that's
> excellent advice.

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you very much, i was going crazy!

Comment: Anytime. Consider looking into extra flags you could compile with, I'm sure ```-Wall``` would have something to say about missing parentheses.